# How to select dynamically added elements with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm loading some html using jQuery function `.load()` and everything works fine. The problem is that I need to select some of the dynamic created elements to apply some styles with JS. For example:

```
$(".new-element-class").datepicker();
```

I know that dynamically added elements are not part of DOM and that I can trigger events this way:

```
$("body").on("click", ".new-element-class", function() {});
```

I have read a lot of answers with that solution but that's not what I need. I want to select and apply a function without having to wait for an event. I also tried `find()` and it didn't work.

Comment: if that so why dont you write the function in document.ready? "I want to select and apply a function without having to wait for an event" this should do your work isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.datepicker()` in the code that adds the new element dynamically. You can do this in the callback function of `.load()`

```
$("#element").load("url", function() {
    $(this).find(".new-element-class").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.